# Including a dependency in Android Studio gives UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, libsodium

I am fairly new to Android programming and am trying to use the libsodium-jni library for some basic Crypto tasks. In Android Studio I add libsodium-jni-aar as a Library Dependency and I can see that this modifies my build.gradle file by adding :

```
compile 'com.github.joshjdevl.libsodiumjni:libsodium-jni-aar:1.0.6'
```

Many of the functions in this library work fine, but when I use the Sodium.sodium_init() function I get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int org.libsodium.jni.SodiumJNI.sodium_init() (tried Java_org_libsodium_jni_SodiumJNI_sodium_1init and Java_org_libsodium_jni_SodiumJNI_sodium_1init__)
                                                                    at org.libsodium.jni.SodiumJNI.sodium_init(Native Method)
```

I'm guessing somehow this is caused by the fact that sodium_init is a native function and for some reason the implementation is not being installed to the phone (or emulator) by gradle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To import a Sonatype repository you need to add this

```
maven {
    url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}
```

to your project build.gradle file in the `allprojects` object which should result in something similar to this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }   
}
```

Then you can add your compile statement in your app build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.joshjdevl.libsodiumjni:libsodium-jni-aar:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added these and the same error is occurring. I can tell that the library is being added because I can safely call some functions in the library without issue. Only when I call the Sodium functions is there a problem.

Comment: Mmm i don't know the library sincerely, but seems [that you are not the only one with problems](https://github.com/joshjdevl/libsodium-jni/issues/66). It's for sure a bug

Comment: Yes I saw that. Being a relative beginner its always easy to assume the problem is with you rather than the library/environment! Ok I will have to think about a workaround then I suppose. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you have 2 options now. 1) change library 2) fork the library on github and see if you can fix it by yourself. Good luck man :)